# json2sstable cassandra gives error like "Upgrade to 1.2.5 first, and run upgradesstables"

Tags: json, cassandra

I want to insert the json data into cassandra sstable using json2sstable option.

My sstable is:

```
cid | key  | ts
101 | ramu | 686
```

I want to put another row using json.

The json file is:

```
[
{"columns": [["cid","102"],["key","raju"],["ts","687"]]}
]
```

I am run the following as:

```
D:\cassandra\bin>json2sstable -K demodb -c data_points
```

I am getting this error..

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:SSTable data_points-e-1-Data.db is too oldto open.  Upgrade to 1.2.5 first, and run upgradesstables
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.fromFilename(Descriptor.java:235)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.fromFilename(Descriptor.java:204)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.<init>(SSTableWriter.java:60)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableImport.importUnsorted(SSTableImport.java:354)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableImport.importJson(SSTableImport.java:335)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableImport.main(SSTableImport.java:559)

ERROR: SSTable data_points-e-1-Data.db is too old to open.  Upgrade to 1.2.5 first, and run upgradesstables"****
```

What can I do?  Please give me any suggestions.
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you running?  Have you recently upgraded?

Comment: I am using cassandra2.0 version but it asking to upgrading.Pls told me how to upgrade the sstable in cassandra

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is the filename that you gave your sstable. The 'e' in your sstable filename indicates the version of the sstable, which Cassandra is checking and rejecting as too old ('e' is from the 0.7 release of Cassandra). I'm guessing you just copied that from an older example. You should look in your data directory at the version that your other sstables are using and use the same one. If you are on 2.0.0 it will be 'ja'; 2.0.1-2.0.5 will be 'jb'.

You should also be aware that json2sstable is mostly used for debugging and testing. If you are doing a bulk load you might want to consider other (more tested) options like the sstableloader.

Comment: I am using jb option also but its showing same error